# WebView shows net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED on HTTPS url

Tags: android, https, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to load an url that fit security protocols with HTTPS, but when I'm trying to load on a WebView, android shows me net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED. Why? is a HTTPS what is the problem?

The source code that shows it is:

```
public class InternalWebBrowserActivityHelperImpl implements InternalWebBrowserActivityHelper, Constants {

    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @NonNull
    private InternalWebBrowserActivityView activityView;

    public InternalWebBrowserActivityHelperImpl(@NonNull InternalWebBrowserActivityView activityView){
        this.activityView = activityView;
    }

    public WebChromeClient getWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

        }
    };

    public WebViewClient getWebViewClient() {

        return new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    LoggerManager.handlesError("onReceivedError", request.getUrl().toString());
                }else{
                    LoggerManager.handlesError("onReceivedError", error.toString());
                }
                activityView.hideLoadingView();
                activityView.showWebView();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                LoggerManager.handlesError("onPageFinished", url);
                activityView.hideLoadingView();
                activityView.showWebView();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                //activityView.showLoadingView();
                LoggerManager.handlesError("override", url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void setupHelper(String url) {
        //7activityView.showLoadingView();
        activityView.showWebView();

        WebSettings.ZoomDensity zoomDensity = WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR;
        activityView.getFullWebView().getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        activityView.getFullWebView().getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // Add this


        activityView.getFullWebView().getSettings().setDefaultZoom(zoomDensity);
        activityView.getFullWebView().getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        activityView.getFullWebView().getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        activityView.getFullWebView().requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

        activityView.getFullWebView().setWebChromeClient(getWebChromeClient);
        activityView.getFullWebView().setWebViewClient(getWebViewClient());

        activityView.getFullWebView().loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The server had a redirection inside to a http site. This was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the URL you give to your webview is in HTTPS ?

Otherwise a quickfix would be to add the below line in your `application` as shown below:

```xml
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ....
</application>
```

I strongly advise that you create the `network_security_config` to only allow your domain and subdomain. Here is a quick [tutorial](https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6)

Comment: i followed this tutorial but not resolved my problem

``<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">ketabenarenji.ir</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>``