# usesCleartextTraffic And NetworkSecurityConfig not permitted

Tags: java, android, kotlin, manifest

i have searched for this problem but cant resolve that problem
i have internet in android 8 but in android 9 dont have any connection

usesCleartextTraffic=true >> not resolved

NetworkSecurityConfig >> not resolved

my url have https and ssl certificate but i dont have any internet connection only in android 9
this is security config below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">ketabenarenji.ir</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: this is full url :> 'https://ketabenarenji.ir/'
and i use wocommerce Rest Api to make Shop App

Comment: You have to use both `useClearTextTraffic` and `android:networkSecurityConfig` in your AndroidManifest in the `<application>` node

Comment: i do that
use both but not responsing

logcat:>> Verification of void ir.ketabenarenji.shop.Global$3.onResponse(java.lang.String) took 126.483ms

Comment: _"my url have https and ssl certificate"_ Then you shouldn't need to worry about "cleartext" etc. That's all about HTTP without the S. Would debugging or having a look at the logcat perhaps reveal anything?

Comment: yes my url have https and ssl
but still not get response Or  error  in Volley

Comment: Yes, and the point was that you shouldn't then need to do anything special, so how did you end up specifying your own `<network-security-config>`? Is it needed? Did you first try without it? Can you now try without it? Or is the problem that you use a self-signed SSL certificate, so Volley refuses to connect to the server?

Comment: i think problem from ssl of the website
because with ssl no need to set security config

Comment: there is some one who knows my problem??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we understood each other, go check my answer in this post [WebView shows net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED on HTTPS url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852523/webview-shows-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-on-https-url/60853719#60853719) it'll help you on how to configure your files.

---

EDIT: I just went on your website and it tells me it's not secure even though you have `https://` you might wanna fix your certificate, once it's fix you can remove all the `useClearTextTraffic` and the file `network_security_config`

Comment: i followed this tutorial but not resolved my problem

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">ketabenarenji.ir</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: i update the post

i use android emulator nexus 5 Api 28

i dont see any error , just volley requests not resonsed or error

Comment: Can you post a code of one call that isn't working ? I've checked and your website is in HTTPS, so you no longer need the `network_config_file` and can delete the attributes `android:usesCleartextTraffic` and `android:networkSecurityConfig` in your `AndroidManifest`